# SCAP Compliance checker error for AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm try to use Scap Compliance Checker 5.4 on a Windows laptop to scan remotely an EC2 Ubuntu 18.04, but it showed error. There's plenty free space on the EC2, and I gave ubuntu full permission to /opt directory as well.

```
insufficient freespace ( MBs) in /opt. Miniumum required is 2048 MB.
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with security. I sugges to move it to Superuser SE.

Comment: It's a security related issue.

Comment: No. *"insufficient freespace"* is **not** a security issue.

Comment: It's very basic Unix stuff. Try `df -h /opt`. In the column `Avail` you will see how much room you have in `/opt`. Your program reports that it needs 2G, so you can easily see how much room you're missing.

Comment: AWS appears to be only a secondary fact to this question, but that being the only tag applied will likely lead to close votes. Also, telling us you have plenty of free space doesn't tell us how much free space you actually have. Please EDIT your question to improve it, showing us what else you've tried and any research that you've done.